# need sudo access when installing homebrew

Tags: homebrew, sudo

i type this code in terminal in visual studio code: /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"

and hit enter and it says "Checking for `sudo` access (which may request your password)...
Password:
but it doesn't let me type anything.

i am on the administrator account

i cant type anything after password

Comment: Stackoverflow is for questions about programming, not general computer usage; [Superuser](https://superuser.com) and [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com) are better places to ask about things like this. But also: does it not let you type anything, or does it just not show anything as you type? Because `sudo` normally doesn't echo anything as you type your password; you enter it blindly and hit return.

Comment: thank you Gordon. i typed my password blindly and it worked